# Push and pop operation for 2D matrix and displaying them in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, stack

I am new to c++ and just learning stack push and pop operation. I have written a small program to push and pop some elements from stack. My sample program is given below:

```
// stack::push/pop
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <stack>          // std::stack

int main ()
{
  std::stack<int> mystack;

  for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) mystack.push(i);

  std::cout << "Popping out elements...";
  while (!mystack.empty())
  {
     std::cout << ' ' << mystack.top();
     mystack.pop();
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

But now I want to push  multiple 3*3 matrix onto the stack and want to get each of them using mystack.top() and also pop each matrix using mystack.pop operation and display the whole matrix. How will I implement the stack for multiple matrix operation?

Sample matrix can be like this:

```
float A[3][3]={{1.0,2.0,3.0},{1.0,2.0,3.0},{1.0,2.0,3.0}};
float B[3][3]={{1.0,2.0,4.0},{1.0,5.0,3.0},{8.0,2.0,3.0}};
```

Comment: So you just use some data structure representing the 3x3 matrix instead of an `int` as template parameter for `std::stack`.

Comment: Sounds like you need to make a matrix class.

Comment: Change the type stored in the stack to be your matrix type.

Comment: can you please show me a demo code? I am very new to this 
@Rob

Comment: can you please give give a little more details? @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @user6823702 `std::stack<Your_Matrix_Type>`.  Don't know what else information you need.

Comment: @user6823702 Well, if you tell my what your matrix type should be.

Comment: At first make sure that your matrix class meets the type requirements of `stack`'s underlying container (`std::deque` in your case).

Comment: I have edited the post @πάντα ῥεῖ

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::array<std::array<float,3>,3>` for this. Plain arrays won't be copied automatically, and do not conform the needs of a data type stored in a `std::queue`:

```
std::array<std::array<float,3>,3> A {{{1.0,2.0,3.0},{1.0,2.0,3.0},{1.0,2.0,3.0}}};
std::array<std::array<float,3>,3> B {{{1.0,2.0,4.0},{1.0,5.0,3.0},{8.0,2.0,3.0}}};
```

Then you can simply define your stack as:

```
std::stack<std::array<std::array<float,3>,3>> myStack;
```

---

To make it more readable and easier to type you can use `using` or a `typedef`:

```
typedef std::array<float,3>,3> My3x3Matrix;

// ...

std::stack<My3x3Matrix> myStack;

myStack.push(A);

// ...

My3x3Matrix C = myStack.top();
myStack.pop();
```

Comment: getting error like : too many initializers for 'std::array<std::array<float, 3u>, 3u>'| @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: can you please provide a complete code for the push and pop operation on 2D matrix? @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @user6823702 Sorry [fixed it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f85d5f9354da00a5)

Comment: @user6823702 _"can you please provide a complete code"_ Well, Stack Overflow isn't meant as a code writing service. I'm pretty sure you're smart enough to figure it out yourself.

Comment: I am confused about how I will push and pop A and B matrix. Will I use mystack.push(A); ? @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @user6823702 Yes of course. That was the whole point of your question, wasn't it?

Comment: Yes. it's working. But is there any way of displaying the whole matrix I am popping each time like I have done in my sample code for a single digit? @ πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @user6823702 You need to write a little helper function to display all the matrix values. But that's another question.

Comment: Can you please show the helper function? I have made a small edit in the question. I want ted to display the matrix but forgot to add. @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: In the more readable version, I getting the following error:
a template-id may not appear in a using-declaration| @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @user6823702 I'm not that familiar with the `using` statement, use a `typedef` instead. Edited answer.

Comment: now getting error: expected unqualified-id before ',' token| @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @user6823702 As mentioned earlier, stop help vampiring please. I'm not going to nanny you through your task. The code I have posted is correct, and if you have issues with it in your particular context post another question please.

Comment: @user6823702 Sorry I had a silly typo in the `std::stack` declaration. Fixed now. But you should have been able to figure that out yourself easily.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `Boost.MultiArray`?

> The classes in this library implement a common interface, formalized
>   as a generic programming concept. The interface design is in line with
>   the precedent set by the C++ Standard Library containers.
>   Boost MultiArray is a more efficient and convenient way to express N-dimensional arrays than existing alternatives (especially the std::vector> formulation of N-dimensional arrays).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Then it sounds like you want to have the following `stack`.

```
typedef boost::multi_array<int, 3> array_type;
std::stack<array_type> s;
```

Comment: I don't see a need to introduce a dependency to boost.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok, but let the man starts experiencing with boost.. :)

Comment: I prefer letting them start within the c++ standard stuff.